# Pivotal HD Hive not able to work with Aggregate functions

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been running some basic scripts on a PHD VM on Hive recently.
Most of the below worked fine on the apache disctribution I used earlier, but now on the PHD version none of the where, sum, group by or basically any operation is responding properly. However the data is available as can be seen in the below o/p of select command.
I get null values for all the operations and queries apart from the 1st select statement below.

Let me know if any one as faced such an issue with their setups.

Creation for table:

```
create external table ytd (video_id string, uploader string, age int, category string, length int, views int, rate float, ratings int, comments int, rid1 string, rid2 string, rid3 string, rid4 string, rid5 string, rid6 string, rid7 string, rid8 string, rid9 string, rid10 string, rid11 string, rid12 string, rid13 string, rid14 string, rid15 string, rid16 string, rid17 string, rid18 string, rid19 string, rid20 string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\n' stored as textfile location '/joker/ytd/crawl';
```

Output for below command:
    select * from ytd limit=5;
6HNrBd4kKMg     AcePuppers      790     News & Politics 75      501976  4.19    1183    3543    ejsaF9T-qL8     EqpOXWAAVRI     khG6N2UGRWY     tzRrqNGd_0o     5Ql-UeMBqDY     UfaTpr4gVFo     FQVeY0l7lzU     2YXpIlh5148     MhoyuDdqpDo     ev17_KL1cU4     MaPiXE83L_c     mh4ryAKDJXM     MS3LcpGEK14     xLs3jASBZNk     86Y4G3__Vi4    vPZdQ6UX8p0      w-5PMs72S-E     msAmWlzNhBE     Gb2LOVbAgoU     67bOAasHv4I     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
_3FrOWdvsNw     PricelessExperience     790     Travel & Places 82      459122  2.24    2028    90      v-qsXESnaWk     Bl43yFLteho     UaZWmloW-Uk     6y-uOKjcAvA    lspMkHCHR4Y      MA_aY3xTJWo     d06xuriAFyA     inAiKQLabsc     5S_-l8haEKs     P2q5rRfGwG0     dGgZ6Uaiotk     Qb7cVBvWxJQ     7ysw0q6jCn4     pXBCiBLWxGg     jygqAAupvxQ     7N3pZhHXSmg     nMOqSul6DOQ     pnigNFLt52Q     NticicE6dmc     mtij0ez5gGw     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ZQgVAD7x5Zo     operation05     790     News & Politics 204     76850   4.36    400     1451    Rk8syX2b-zQ     vs7T4XEhg6k     uK3isbd0YOQ     S-py0ooWFFM     vzVMQht96bM     qPCjIXEu_tA     7b2JLENkflw     bhm8ylJu79g     Nuz3K__ipJ0     fVe4Ovu-nfg     JgPkXrMdTTo     GhUbMQMUSQk     4qCjvTPTtng     Mi5dOtcF8eQ     30_bW6vux7A    xh0b9WBp9jw      hLCU6QRi9Pw     B0gFx-XU5uo     eHqaaLHZHoc     cSbZmd-l8n8     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
6vbwQ34Lvks     StaffGrillo     790     News & Politics 307     218869  4.85    763     298     9uwcfXrXsW0     -yjN0pQ8Mgw     XoxW2ANtOfE     4b7SXGrkR0c     z5-WoRYUVgs     nWQT9w5rjMk     jc_unBhZLZg     ZCAUx9mk-I4     In5NsN9NXQ8     PF7_uct1qN4     -KspAAEbWBM     5UIoZIhv1t4     JF6xgrubtsM     M3gBhLdJhbw     F9I0hl_Eo4k    kEGkbkhltGw      b3FyIW2J2ek     9jps_FUI_LA     7w55tR_wrFs     zj4N6PHNZ10     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
WUZ3sZT8BcA     ntcoolfool      790     News & Politics 54      209286  3.44    334     787     _ahlduhEXQY     QtyBNKAeV6o     xLs3jASBZNk     3E9hVdbWg-E     6HNrBd4kKMg     ZQgVAD7x5Zo     5Ql-UeMBqDY     ay3f_celUxU     EqpOXWAAVRI     tzRrqNGd_0o     SJjPvyPzvog     t9QxHtptvn0     C3PcWx3cgV8     FQVeY0l7lzU     qsZmiGKkSLU    2YXpIlh5148      mh4ryAKDJXM     qPCjIXEu_tA     yUyp4t0j8Ow     QONWDfQgSIk     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

Other sqls tried.
    select category, count(*) from ytd group by category;
    select category, count(video_id) from ytd group by category;
    select distinct category from ytd;
    select count(distinct(video_id)) from ytd;

Explain plan for another sql.
    explain select count(*) from ytd where category='News & Politics';

OK
ABSTRACT SYNTAX TREE:
  (TOK_QUERY (TOK_FROM (TOK_TABREF (TOK_TABNAME ytd))) (TOK_INSERT (TOK_DESTINATION (TOK_DIR TOK_TMP_FILE)) (TOK_SELECT (TOK_SELEXPR (TOK_FUNCTIONSTAR count))) (TOK_WHERE (= (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL category) 'News & Politics'))))

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Alias -> Map Operator Tree:
        ytd
          TableScan
            alias: ytd
            Filter Operator
              predicate:
                  expr: (category = 'News & Politics')
                  type: boolean
              Select Operator
                Group By Operator
                  aggregations:
                        expr: count()
                  bucketGroup: false
                  mode: hash
                  outputColumnNames: _col0
                  Reduce Output Operator
                    sort order:
                    tag: -1
                    value expressions:
                          expr: _col0
                          type: bigint
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          aggregations:
                expr: count(VALUE._col0)
          bucketGroup: false
          mode: mergepartial
          outputColumnNames: _col0
          Select Operator
            expressions:
                  expr: _col0
                  type: bigint
            outputColumnNames: _col0
            File Output Operator
              compressed: false
              GlobalTableId: 0
              table:
                  input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                  output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat

Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1

Comment: Pls show the error output.

Comment: @javadba "I get null values for all the operations and queries apart from the 1st select statement below."
There is no error. Every time a execute the sqls below:
select category, count(*) from ytd group by category; select category, count(video_id) from ytd group by category; select distinct category from ytd; select count(distinct(video_id)) from ytd;
I get null output, as if the values I'm fetching do not exist.
For example:
select count(*) from ytd where category='News & Politics';
should return the count of all rows where category is News & Politics, but I keep getting null as the o/p

Comment: I created an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of seeing nulls is a mismatch between the datatypes in the on-disk files and the DDL of the external table.

Try this:

```
select category from ytd limit 10;
```

You will probably see all null's - which is a symptom of the problem described.  I suspect that you have a datatype mismatch between the external file and your table definition. In that case select * still APPEARS to work but it is a mirage. You need to select individual column(s) to verify the ddl were correct.